# PHP GET - HTACCESS re-write / Reading a URL by ID?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to rewrite and get ID from a URL:

I am using a Ticket Script that gets the content from mysql database by ID. And i was wondering If we could get the ID from url by only typing the site.com/ID HERE.

Our Main URL looks like:  **site.com/index.php?id=1A2VD4**

But how to READ and GET the ID using URL: **site.com/1A2VD4**

The Htaccess I am using:

- RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1½

  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1

I tried a lot different GET methods and Regular Expression in my php code, but not luck at all / Centos / Apache 2.2! I will be appereciated if I could get some help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in root's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Inside `index.php` you can this id by using `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Edited *Again*: It works now! I had to change my GET code! You are trully an amazing helper! God bless! Thank you so much for your time and efforts!

Comment: Your `index.php` is going to be loaded anyway for all those URLs but you should get `$_GET['id']` with the value of URI

Comment: your simply amazing! Well I am using mysql_real_escap. And seems to work fine.. It managed to add the GET in all my files and it works without a doubt! I have also a simple question. I have different files that also uses the ID. For example we had the index.php, and I have another one caleld getticket.php and they are all in the same folder. I am on shared hosting so all the folders are reading the index.php first. I was wondering if I could also the ID for the getticket.php file too! But so far so good. All done very well! You have really saved my work! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. You can possibly have pretty URL scheme like `http://site.com/<php-file-name-without-extension>/<id>` So for ex: URL of `http://site.com/getticket/1A2VD4` will be internally rewritten as `http://site.com/getticket.php?id=1A2VD4`

Comment: Also if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.